# HP fortify scan in Ios getting error

Tags: fortify

Hi I am trying to generate reaport but I am getting warning as below and not generating report.Could you please help me out?

[warning]: NST file: /Users/xxxx/.fortify/sca6.2/build/yyyyy/Classes/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m.nst does not exist or removed.

I am using below steps for scanning code. I am getting warning in third step during scanning code apart from step 1 & 2 are working for me.

1. sourceanalyzer-4.21 -b ${project} -clean
2. sourceanalyzer-4.21 -Xmx3G -debug -b ${project} -logfile ${project}-trans.log xcodebuild -project ${project}.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator7.1
3. sourceanalyzer-4.21 -Xmx3G -b ${project} -scan -f ${project}.fpr
4. ReportGenerator -format pdf -f ${project}.pdf -source ${project}.fpr

Comment: What is the command that you're using to generate the report? Does the problem repeat when you do a clean scan then new scan?

Comment: Are you trying to scan Matlab code?

Answer (score 0):

Fortify generates NST files during compilation, these NST files together generate one combined FPR file.
If NST files are not generated, then you may not get an appropriate fpr.

> sourceanalyzer-4.21 -Xmx3G -debug -b ${project} -logfile ${project}-trans.log xcodebuild -project ${project}.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator

If you want to use iphoneos sdk, you must make sure that "i386" is listed in the Valid Architectures setting.